# flask-security - duplicate current_user.uuid values

Tags: python, flask-security

I'm using [FlaskBootStrapSecurity project](https://github.com/hansonkd/FlaskBootstrapSecurity) which uses Flask Security. I have a situation where the flask.ext.security current_user has the same uuid for 2 users.

For example,

1. I log in with one user
2. print  `current_user.uuid`
3. log out
4. log in with a different user
5. print `current_user.uuid`

and it is the same value for both  users.

This occurs when I deploy to `nginx` but not when I run with `python manage.py runserver`.